# What is wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion

The question asks why people think ganja should be legal.

One of the strongest arguments that is repeated again and again and again is that ganja is simply not dangerous.

[What policy arguments do people make in favor of legalizing marijuana?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/what-policy-arguments-do-people-make-in-favor-of-legalizing-marijuana/30698#30698)

Is this true? Well, that's not the question is. But yea, it looks correct.

No body dies due to ganja overdose almost literally. Some anecdotal evidence of one or 2 dies due to ganja.

Yet the question is downvoted.

They accused me of having "agenda". What agenda do they think I have? I don't even post pictures I made. I post pictures that someone else made in 9gag. That whole pic is an argument in favor of ganja legalization. It's simply not dangerous.

What am I missing here? What policy arguments do people make in favor of legalizing marijuana. Well, it's not dangerous. Why even bother criminalizing it in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

In the past, we have been very tolerant with the very low-quality posts from both your accounts. However, trying to build a health argument around a random image from 9gag is crossing a line. I'm removing the answer. We may not have a strict [“back it up” rule for answers](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/101), but this is far below any reasonable quality threshold.

If you want the answer restored, edit it to back up your health argument with *solid* sources, preferably peer-reviewed medical studies. You'll also need to point to solid sources for the various other claims you make. Just saying that "many have point that out" & "as people repeatedly say" is not good enough.

It also wouldn't hurt if you at least tried to improve your writing style. You'll find tons of advice and guidance in your previous [Meta discussion](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-can-i-improve-this-question).

Comment: +1 But I don't think sources need to be at the level of peer-reviewed studies. Especially considering that the question is "What arguments do people make", so the argument doesn't necessarily have to be true. What a good answer should do though is show that people actually make that argument (which a random image from 9gag really doesn't do). The question is a bit of a mess in general (and would probably be closed nowadays), but I think that some answer of the form "Libertarians argue that legalized marijuana is beneficial to society because X (see example Y)" might be valid.

Comment: @tim Sure. Went a bit overboard there. Updated the answer.

Comment: FWIW it seems to me that cannabis being less toxic and addictive than alcohol or tobacco - and indeed pretty benign compared to the latter - is fairly mainstream. Ask any reasonably well informed weed smoker and you'll get that argument pretty much verbatim.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy The comparison in the image isn't with alcohol or tobacco, it's with soda. That said, I don't disagree that if you look hard enough you might find the kernel of a half decent answer hidden somewhere in there. And of course, I could have simply removed the image. This isn't the point, though. The answer wasn't deleted for being off topic, it was deleted for being the latest in a stream of crap. Several people have wasted their time trying to help the OP improve their posts. With no success. If anything, the OP's posts have been declining in quality. This needs to stop.

Comment: No disagreement on OP and her (his?) posts, but even with soda cannabis [probably compares well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBnniua6-oM).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy (you're preaching to the choir)